# show results if it matches any of the conditions?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

This is driving me nuts. I'm checking 3 conditions in my sql query. If any of them match, I want to grab the result `campaign_id`:

```
SELECT `campaign_id` FROM `tracking` 
WHERE `user` = 'username@domain.net' AND `attempts` > '5' 
    AND `clicked` > '0' AND `shared` > '0'
```

From what I can tell, the way it works now is it has to match ALL the conditions. How can I make it show the results of `campaign_id` if it matches **ANY** of the conditions?

Comment: Change the `AND`s to `OR`s perhaps?

Comment: I thought the same. It pulled records for other users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `AND` to `OR`. But only for the parts that you want OR'd, using parentheses

```
SELECT `campaign_id` FROM `tracking` 
WHERE `user` = 'username@domain.net' AND (`attempts` > '5' 
    OR `clicked` > '0' OR `shared` > '0')
```

Basically, you want the specified user `AND` any of these other filters that are grouped together using internal `OR`s

Comment: This makes the user become part of the OR. It has to match the user I'm searching. The way you have it now it can match 4 conditions, not 3.

Comment: @john Sorry, I updated it after seeing your above statement. Should work now

Comment: never mind the parentheses fix that. Worked perfect thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 2):

If you want ANY as opposed to ALL then you need to replace the AND operators with OR operators. If you need to mix ANDs and ORs then make sure you get the precedence right; the easiest way to do this is to wrap relating conditions in parentheses). For example, if you always want to match the user and then any of the other conditions then

```
SELECT `campaign_id` 
FROM `tracking` 
WHERE `user` = 'username@domain.net' 
  AND (   `attempts` > '5' 
       OR `clicked` > '0' 
       OR `shared` > '0'
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit either `attempts`, `clicked` or `shared` while just going by that specific user, do something like:

```
SELECT `campaign_id` 
FROM `tracking` 
WHERE `user` = 'username@domain.net' 
    AND (`attempts` > '5' 
    OR `clicked` > '0' 
    OR `shared` > '0')
```